# How to find the recent popular images, videos, site - by subject

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, api, youtube-api

I am looking for some way to dynamically determine popular images, videos, sites, etc. about a certain topic. For example, if the topic is "Ford", I would like to be able to find most recent/popular images, videos, websites about Ford.

Are there APIs (from Google, YouTube, Facebook, etc.) that would let me do this?

For example, from a browser, I can do a google search for "Ford" images added in the last week. Can I do the same programmatically?

Similar question for YouTube, Facebook, etc.

(I would be able to use it via AJAX or PHP.)

Any suggestions would he appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the API of each service. The main services on the internet such as Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc provides an API where you can find the most of the infos that you commented above.

You also can use javascript in all of them.

Follows some links:

Twitter
https://dev.twitter.com/

Facebook
https://developers.facebook.com/

Youtube
https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

Google +
https://developers.google.com/+/api/

Google Web Seach
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

Comment: Thanks. I see that youtube provides what I need. I'm doing more research.

Does the Facebook API allow to search for a TOPIC? For example, if I want to find the most recent posts about Ford, can I do that? I don't want to search through MY newsfeed, I want to search for posts related to a topic across the entirety of Facebook, at least from commercial members (Ford company, etc.). In other words, a way to find the most popular (based on likes and shares) posts regarding Ford.

Comment: You can explorer better doing some tests with this tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=100003877508183%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname

Comment: If the answer was enough. Tick as answer. Thanks